# URL Rewrite update protocol and domain if URL is http://

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect all calls to http://www.domain.com/csp/ to https://secure.doman.com/csp/ using URL rewrite running on IIS 8.5. I would like the URL on the browser to update accordingly.  I cannot get it to work.

Below is the section of the web.config file with the rule

```
     <rules>
    <rule name="CSP to SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^http://www.domain.com/csp/(.*)$" />
       <conditions>
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^http://" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://secure.domain.com/csp/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to peterviola's reply at http://forums.iis.net/t/1214515.aspx?Change+to+https+and+adjust+domain+if+URL+uses+http+and+matches+a+particular+path I managed to get to the solution I was seeking.

```
           <rule name="csp2HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)csp/(.*$)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="csp2subdomain" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)csp/(.*$)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.|)domain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://secure.domain.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

*The above solution works. I can't understand why this could not be done using one rule.*

Hope this helps.